# Event Binding/ Unbinding with Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events, javascript-framework

I want to observe for two custom events via the prototype framework and unbind one of them.

Meaning, when the browser loads the DOM elements, I want to register the following events: "customEvent:Task1" and "customEvent:Task2". These two events are observed on the whole page.

When "customEvent:Task1" is called/executed, I want to unbind/ unregister the "customEvent:Task2" event on the page. When "customEvent:Task2" is called, it just executes a function.

So how can I register (bind) and unregister (unbind) events using the prototype framework.

**Edit:**
The registered customEvents are not bound to an element but are available through out the page. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) for something global like the document itself:
<sup>(`Event.on` is new to Prototype 1.7)</sup>

```
document.on('customEvent:Task1', function(event, element) {
    if (customEventTask2) customEventTask2.stop();
});
var customEventTask2 = document.on('customEvent:Task1', function(event, element) {
    // This is your second event type
});
```

Then of course all that remains is to [`fire`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/fire/) some events.

```
document.fire('customEvent:Task1');
document.fire('customEvent:Task2'); // Should not fire
```